# Почему JQuery не меняет цвет текста после клика

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery должен при нажатии на кнопку менять ее цвет фона и цвет текста. Почему-то меняется только цвет заднего фона, а цвет текста не хочет меняться ни при каких обстоятельствах. Аналогичный код у всех работает.

```js
$('.done_button').click(function(){
  $(this).css({
    "background": "#36FF17",
    "color": "#000000!important",
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="task unselectable">
    <div class="task_name">Задача</div>
    <div class="done_button unselectable">Сделано</div>
    <div class="not_done_button unselectable">Не сделано</div>
</div>
```

Comment: html код приложите

Comment: Вы меняете цвет на черный, а он и так черный.

Comment: `!important` уберите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно убрать `!important` в свойстве `color`, так как при использовании функции `css()`, данные стили добавляются автоматически в сам тег:

То есть при нажатии на *Сделано*, то jQuery поменяет тег следующим образом

```
<div 
  class="done_button unselectable"
  style="background: rgb(54, 255, 23); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Сделано
</div>
```

```js
$('.done_button').click(function(){
  $(this).css({
    "background": "#36FF17",
    "color": "#ff0019",
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="task unselectable">
    <div class="task_name">Задача</div>
    <div class="done_button unselectable">Сделано</div>
    <div class="not_done_button unselectable">Не сделано</div>
</div>
```